# Is 'shake' as verb correct in this context?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Let's say there is a lot of dirt on my shirt or on my bed sheet and I need to clean it, or say my shirt is very wet and I need to get rid of excess water.

What is the appropriate verb to describe this action? It is similar to **shaking**: you will hold the two ends and then shake it kind of hardly to get rid of water or dirt, but does *shake* really describe what I want to say?

I also looked up **snap** but I'm not sure if that is applicable here.

Comment: "snap" would not be normally be applicable here (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Shake" is acceptable in this context, often expressed as "shake it out." Examples:

- I shook all of the dust off of my bed sheet.
- I need to shake all of the water out of my shirt (although you might have better luck *wringing* it out if it is soaked with water).
- Go shake the mud off of your pants outside before coming into my house.